# Is a quadratic regression model valid if its y-intercept is not significant?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I am testing my data with a quadratic regression model (`y = ax^2 + bx +c`).  The results of testing the model are:

```
P-value of a:< 2e-16    
P-value of b:< 2e-16
P-value of c: 0.643
F(DF=138):55.58
P-value of model: < 2.2e-16 
R^2: 0.4461
```

As the P-value of `c` is higher than 0.05, does that mean the quadratic model not valid? Or should I simply remove the `c` from the model? What does its nonsignificance imply?

Comment: thanks @Glen_b. it's actually a species diversity vs environmental parameter analysis.

Comment: SInce that comment of mine seems to have evolved into a partial answer I'll copy it down and try to address some more of your question below

Comment: This seems clear enough to me. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a strong basis to remove the constant you should not generally do so (an example of a potentially reasonable reason to remove the constant is the prior consideration that at $x=0$ the response must be 0 - such as when modelling braking distance as a function of speed for cars under standardized conditions).

But even then, there may be good reasons why - within the range of the data - a model with an intercept would still be a reasonable choice. Outside a physical model like that, it's very like removing the intercept for a linear fit and it's a somewhat similar consideration to removing a non-significant main effect when an interaction term is present. In both cases the usual advice is something like "don't do it without a really good reason. If you have a really good reason then think about it very carefully, and then you still probably don't do it"

Some people advise never removing it, but I think that it's reasonable in some situations. (I wouldn't include mere non-significance among them.)

[There are many threads on site relating to both the intercept in a straight line fit and leaving out main effects when there's an interaction; it may be worth exploring via search.]

A non-significant intercept doesn't mean that the quadratic model is "not valid", it simply means that where the parabola crosses the $y$-axis (i.e. at $x=0$) the estimate of the average $y$-value is not distinguishable from 0.

from comments:

> it's [...] a species diversity vs environmental parameter analysis

I assume then that you don't have a theoretical basis for thinking that the relationship must be quadratic (even though it might be a good description); in that case I'd say that there's really no reason to consider doing anything with the intercept term. It's unlikely to be worth worrying about at all (that it's not significant, I mean). I'd advise you to keep it in the model; and of itself it presents no reason to doubt the model.

---

Response to comment under answer:

If you have a response that cannot go negative you should generally consider models that have the same property; in those situations you should typically expect to find some particular characteristics (smaller variance when the mean gets small, for example) that would make an ordinary linear model unsuitable, and good model choice can respect the constraint on the mean as well as match such characteristics

Comment: I support this good advice. Note that for your "parameter" $x$ (statistical people really would prefer that you said _property_ or _variable_ to follow diversity $= ax^2 + bx$ it should be true that diversity is $0$ when $x = 0$, Note that a quadratic could predict negative diversity somewhere, so it sounds a dubious model without some extra device (e.g. logarithmic link in  a generalised linear model). (That is, I know of no diversity measure that is ever negative.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, maybe some extra work is needed to add to the model. And yes, no diversity measure should be negative as far as I know.

Comment: @wwwwwwww If you have a response that cannot go negative you should generally consider models that have the same property; in those situations you should typically expect to find some particular characteristics (smaller variance when the mean gets small, for example) that would make an ordinary linear model unsuitable, and good model choice can respect the constraint on the mean as well as match such characteristics.